# Best way to catch Xaml errors in Xamarin in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and not a big fan of WPF. I'm taking a course on Udemy and the instructor is showing how to catch xaml errors at compile time. The problem is, the current version of Xamarin that comes with VS 2019 isn't catching the error. I've been Googling for a while and all I came up with is to try a global exception handler and telling the compiler to compile xaml in the assembly.cs (which is now the default). Can anyone point me in a good direction?

Here is my Xaml page - **TypeArgumen** should be invalid:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="HelloWorld.GreetPage">

    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArgumen="Thickness"
            Android="0,0,0,0"
            iOS="0,30,0,0">
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>

    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">

        <BoxView Color="Green" Opacity="{Binding Value}" />

        <Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}'}" 
                Opacity="{Binding Value}" />

        <Slider x:Name="slider"></Slider>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is my assembly.cs file:

```
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
```

Here is my Code behind:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class GreetPage : ContentPage
    {
        public GreetPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            slider.Value = .5;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0);
            else if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                Padding = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
            {
                System.Exception ex = (System.Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: x:TypeArgumen="Thickness" should be x:TypeArgument="Thickness"

Comment: I know but thanks. My question is how do I get the compiler to tell me that? =)

Comment: I'm not sure - I would expect that to cause a compiler error.  Possibly file a bug with the XF team

Comment: Maybe that's why they added the C# ContentPage? To give programmers a hint to do things in the code behind? Works for me.

Comment: Oddly enough, VS 2017 reports that error, but 2019 doesn't. But there are a lot of Xaml errors that aren't caught by any edition of Visual Studio. Extensions like XamRight (https://criticalhittech.com/xamright/) on Visual Studio and MFractor on VS for Mac help fill the gap in many cases.  Disclaimer: I develop XamRight, because I felt these frustrations.

Comment: Well, I'm a Winforms person so I would feel more comfortable doing everything in the code-behind anyway. I don't trust myself to type a lot of Xaml correctly the first time.